# Request timed out error on copying data in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am receiving the below error on running a copy activity in my adf pipeline. My source and sink are cosmos db containers in different subscription. ADF pipeline is created in subscription which has target(sink) cosmos db container.

Error:

> Error code 2200 Failure type User configuration issue
>
> Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestTimeoutException,Message=Request
> timed out. ActivityId: 0d2b8ebb-090d-43eb-8494-f82e53b3134b, Request
> URI: /dbs/ZLQDAA==/colls/ZLQDAIez1wo=/docs, RequestStats: , SDK:
> documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.5.1 Host/64-bit
> MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,''Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A
> task was
> canceled.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestTimeoutException,Message=Request
> timed out. ActivityId: 0d2b8ebb-090d-43eb-8494-f82e53b3134b, Request
> URI: /dbs/ZLQDAA==/colls/ZLQDAIez1wo=/docs, RequestStats: , SDK:
> documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.5.1 Host/64-bit
> MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,''Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A
> task was
> canceled.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestTimeoutException,Message=Request
> timed out. ActivityId: 0d2b8ebb-090d-43eb-8494-f82e53b3134b, Request
> URI: /dbs/ZLQDAA==/colls/ZLQDAIez1wo=/docs, RequestStats: , SDK:
> documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.5.1 Host/64-bit
> MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,''Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A
> task was
> canceled.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestTimeoutException,Message=Request
> timed out. ActivityId: 0d2b8ebb-090d-43eb-8494-f82e53b3134b, Request
> URI: /dbs/ZLQDAA==/colls/ZLQDAIez1wo=/docs, RequestStats: , SDK:
> documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.5.1 Host/64-bit
> MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,''Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A
> task was canceled.,Source=mscorlib,'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official documentation

Cosmos DB limits single request’s size to 2MB. The formula is Request Size = Single Document Size * Write Batch Size. If you hit error saying “Request size is too large.”, **reduce the writeBatchSize value in copy sink configuration.**

**Page size:** The number of documents per page of the query result. Default is "-1" which uses the service dynamic page up to 1000.

**Throughput:** Set an optional value for the number of RUs you'd like to apply to your CosmosDB collection for each execution of this data flow during the read operation. Minimum is 400.

Comment: I have the error printed in detail above. i am not getting Request size is too large. its request timed out. please check the error message. I tried with writebatchSize as empty and by putting value of 2000. the error is same in both case